# Unexpected behaviour after changing a user's password in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I'm creating a cpanel type of interface where my webhosting customers can do simple things like change their ftp password, email password or mysql password. The PHP script which changes the user's MySQL password, works fine! However, it stops denying access to the root mysql user. Why is that happening? I've understood that it happens when the script does a "FLUSH PRIVILEGES", but why so? I don't see that I'm changing the root mysql user's password anywhere!

```
$query = "UPDATE mysql.user SET Password=PASSWORD(?) WHERE User=?;";
$res = $db->prepare($query);
$res->bind_param('ss',$_POST['new_mysql_password'],$_POST['mysql_user_name']); 
$res->execute();

$query = "FLUSH PRIVILEGES;";
$res = $db->prepare($query);
$res->execute();
```

Comment: is this the actual user connected on the script connection to mysql

Comment: are you asking me if I'm trying to change password for the same user which is connected on the script? Then the answer is no

Comment: _'it stops denying access to the root mysql user'_ Now root mysql user allow to access?

Comment: Okay problem spotted! I was mistakingly putting 'si' instead of 'ss' in bind parameters, thereby changing the MySQL password for each and every user on MySQL server!!

Comment: Should I delete the question? Since it was not really an issue but a stupid mistake from my side which is not even there in the sample code I've posted here!

Comment: @iamlegend you could edit question 'ss' - > 'si'. And add an your own answer.